# Python list of Dictionaries and create another dictionary from particular case

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries.

```
    data = [
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T05:57:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - Session id kajdhrg7uhdfvbshfgadf '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'JHUSHDVCHBASJd'},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'asdfawerg cdv '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'fya7 5 Lorem Ipsum Rebolt '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'zxcgwrt asdfg w4e6354gdf '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'zcfb26 eqrgsfdb syh2456ytdfg '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'we57hb354gf '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:59:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - sdfsum Rebolt '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:59:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - sdfsum Rebolt '}
    ]
```

It is a log pattern. But error logs new line doesn't have `[FANATIC]` and it should be in single line or single message.

Is there any way to have those in a new dictionary with conjugated message for the errors only?

```
for i in data:
    if "[FANATIC]" in i['messages'] and "exception" in i['messages']:
        print(i)
```

Is there anyway I can catch 'in between lines' to a new dictionary?

EDIT:

What I want is similar to below...:

```
data = [
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt '},
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'JHUSHDVCHBASJd'},
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'asdfawerg cdv '},
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'fya7 5 Lorem Ipsum Rebolt '},
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'zxcgwrt asdfg w4e6354gdf '},
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'zcfb26 eqrgsfdb syh2456ytdfg '},
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'we57hb354gf '},
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z', 'messages': [
'[FANATIC] - - Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt', 
'JHUSHDVCHBASJd', 
'asdfawerg cdv ', 
'fya7 5 Lorem Ipsum Rebolt ',
'zxcgwrt asdfg w4e6354gdf ',
'we57hb354gf '
]
},
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - sdfsum Rebolt '},
{'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - sdfsum Rebolt '}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the exception to an intermediate list and then store the list in another list

```
from pprint import pprint
data = [
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T05:57:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - Session id kajdhrg7uhdfvbshfgadf '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'JHUSHDVCHBASJd'},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'asdfawerg cdv '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'fya7 5 Lorem Ipsum Rebolt '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'zxcgwrt asdfg w4e6354gdf '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'zcfb26 eqrgsfdb syh2456ytdfg '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:58:12.722Z','messages': 'we57hb354gf '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:59:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt '},
    {'@timestamp': '2018-10-29T06:59:12.722Z','messages': '[FANATIC] - - Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt '}
]
counter=0
exceptionlist=[]
while(counter<len(data)):
    if "[FANATIC]" in data[counter]['messages']:
        oneexception=[ data[counter]['messages']]
        counter+=1
        while (counter<len(data) and "[FANATIC]" not in data[counter]['messages'] ):
            oneexception.append( data[counter]['messages'])
            counter+=1
        exceptionlist.append( oneexception)
pprint(exceptionlist)
```

OUTPUT

```
[['[FANATIC] - - Session id kajdhrg7uhdfvbshfgadf '],
 ['[FANATIC] - - Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt ',
  'JHUSHDVCHBASJd',
  'asdfawerg cdv ',
  'fya7 5 Lorem Ipsum Rebolt ',
  'zxcgwrt asdfg w4e6354gdf ',
  'zcfb26 eqrgsfdb syh2456ytdfg ',
  'we57hb354gf '],
 ['[FANATIC] - - Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt '],
 ['[FANATIC] - - Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt ']]
```

Comment: @Abin Paul Can you please have a loot at my EDIT?

Answer (score 2):

Just filter your list with a comprehension:

```
res = [x for x in data if x["messages"].startswith("[FANATIC]")]
```

Or for both checks:

```
res2 = [x for x in data if all(s in x["messages"] for s in ("Exception", "FANATIC"))]
```

For getting whatever is "in between lines" you can strip from left and right:

```
def StriptStuff(s):
    return s.lstrip("[FANATIC] -").rstrip("- Exception Lorem Ipsum Rebolt ")

res2 = [StriptStuff(x["messages"]) for x in data if all(s in x["messages"] for s in ("Exception", "FANATIC"))]
```

But for more complicated stuff a `regex` would be better.

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/TastyQuirkyPatch)

Comment: How does this catch the 'in between lines'?

Comment: Thank you. I wanted things similar to Albin Paul.